Sylius InvoicingPlugin : Hi, how can I customize the design of the PDF invoice using the InvoicingPlugin?
Someone has already customized the position of the content for PDF invoices using the InvoicingPlugin in Sylius.
Iwantto change de position of the the seller and the buyer, change logo, and change the color of the invoice. I use from vendor the  InvoicingPlugin and i can't change something in the invoice

To customize the appearance of PDF invoices generated by SyliusInvoicingPlugin, you need to overwrite Twig templates.

Find the pdf.html.twig and/or pdfLayout.html.twig files in the vendor/sylius/invoicing-plugin/src/Resources/views/Invoice/Download/ directory and copy them to the templates/bundles/SyliusInvoicingPlugin/Invoice/Download/ directory in your Sylius project.
Make the necessary changes to the design, logo, or color scheme in the copied files.
Clear the Symfony cache using the bin/console cache:clear

More on how to overwrite twig templates in symfony bundle
or check out how to overwrite sylius templates
